# How to confirm id is not present in jasmine test case

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am writing jasmine test cases for angularjs testing. In one view student can't see the button. I am checking based on id length but i am getting `expected '1' instead of '0'`. Button is not there in view still it can see the id.

Is there any other condition to check?

```
element.all(by.id('create_course_button')).then(function(items) {
  expect(items.length).toBe(0);
});
```

Comment: could you please share your page HTML code? based on your provide code, the element *does exist* in DOM but is not visible on GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your button **is still present in the DOM** but being hidden by css `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`.

If that is correct, you could use `.isDisplayed()` API of WebdriverJS to check if the element is being displayed or not:

```
expect(element(by.id('create_course_button')).isDisplayed()).toEqual(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try    `expect(by.id('create_course_button')).not.toExist();`

you can also try:

```
expect($(document)).not.toContain($el);
```

another suggestion:

```
expect('#create_course_button').not.toExist();
```

Comment: When i used toContain i got TypeError: Object By.id("create_course_button") has no method 'indexOf'
when i used toExist i got  TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toExist'

Comment: can you try expect('#create_course_button').not.toExist() ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for visibility use `isDisplayed()`

```
expect($('#foo').isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

If you want to test if the element is present in the DOM use `browser.isElementPresent()`

```
expect(browser.isElementPresent(by.css('#foo'))).toBe(false);
```

Remember that you  need to pass a locator to `browser.isElementPresent(by.xxx)`

Comment: I get `Cannot find name 'browser'` when using this in Angular2+. Can you please advise from where to include `browser`?